# stuck in realtime plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to run this in python 2.7.10 with backend 'QTAgg', but it seems that the figure will freeze after the plot is over and I have to force quit the figure. Can anyone give me some advise? Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.xlim(0,20)
plt.ylim(0,1)
plt.ion()
y = []
i = 0
while i<100:
    temp = np.random.random()
    i += 1
    y.append(temp)
    if i>20:
        plt.xlim(i-20,i)
    plt.plot(y)
    plt.pause(0.1)
```

Comment: What OS and version of matplotlib?

Comment: @wflynny windows7 with matplotlib 1.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this kind of usage don't have a correct way to exit plotting, which cause an infinite loop I guess. The best way is use matplotlib.animation, which is so powerful.